# Learning Python the Hard Way ex40, i dont understand the __init__ part

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

Im having difficulties understanding whats happening on line 3-4 in this exercise in Learn Python The Hard Way.

```
1 class Song(object):
2
3     def __init__(self, lyrics): # This part
4         self.lyrics = lyrics
5
6     def sing_me_a_song(self):
7         for line in self.lyrics:
8             print line
9
10 happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
11                    "I don't want to get sued",
12                    "So I'll stop right there"])
13
14 bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family",
15                         "With pockets full of shells"])
16
17 happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()
18
19 bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Im reading the excercise over and over again but i dont understand what is happening. Why the 2 arguments? Why is it formatted like self.lyrics?